# Python Flask - Store input values into variables then print it

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I am trying to get users amount of coins saved to my flask project. So users are supposed to write in a input field how much coins they want to display, for instance "1200", then I want flask to receive that and print it on my table I have. I have done some research, and also tried copy a bit of code from my "contact" form, but no luck at all!

Here is my HTML code:

```
div class="search_div">
    <form action="GET">
      <input type="text" class="coins-box" placeholder="Amount of Coins" />
    </form>
  </div>
```

Here is my python code:

```
@app.route('/bflipper', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def bFlipper():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        userInput = request.form['input']
        return render_template('flipper.html', userInput=userInput)
```

I mainly want it to be stored into a variable on python, as I need to add some other stuff with that user input later on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a global variable and assign value to it inside the function

```
my_value = ""
@app.route('/bflipper', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def bFlipper():
    if request.method == 'GET':
         global my_value
         my_value = request.form['input']
```